# What math do I need to convert numbers according to this table?

Tags: math

Given an X, what math is needed to find its Y, using this table?

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |

This is a language agnostic problem. I can't just store the array, and do the lookup. The input will always be the finite set of 0 to 6. It won't be scaling later.

Comment: belongs on http://mathoverflow.com as the question is purely math.

Comment: You can very easily construct an algebraic equation from this.

Comment: Is this homework, and does a switch statement count as "just storing the array"?

Comment: It's not purely math. There are answers that use no modulo, answers that use no conditionals etc. I think it fits here just fine.

Comment: I was an advanced undergraduate in math, and continued to learn things after graduating.  However, any question on Math Overflow that I can understand is tagged "soft-question".

Comment: no, not homework. work work. just been awake far too long, and brain too foggy from allergy meds right now. just needed this last bit to work so i can commit it and get some sleep.  the no array was just a waste of memory to create the array, to do a 1 time lookup, then throw it away when i knew there was a math way, just could not brain.

Comment: @Uberfuzzy, you're really that strapped for memory you can't spare 7 (or maybe 28) bytes?  Plus, if it's not homework and not a performance bottleneck, you should generally use the code that expresses the intention best.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: My response to that would be: he should provide an efficient calculation (e.g., Guffa's answer), but provide an explanation for why it works in comments. Best of both worlds that way (in my opinion).

Comment: @Dan, the most efficient solution may well be a table lookup (perhaps through a switch).  It probably expresses intention better than an arbitrary arithmetic expression.  And of course, a common problem with comments for simple things is that the code changes but they don't.

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, both good points actually.

Comment: Don't commit stuff when you are sleepy, just writing code at low brain power is something that should be avoided. But if you are too busy to follow that rule, at least give it a second inspection after you have slept. If you are too tired to deal with a linear equation, what mess couldn't you make facing more complex problems?

Comment: @Dan and Matthew: Then my solution with the magic number expressed in octal would be almost self documenting. Better would be to put it in Hex and change it multiply by 4. I'll go update it ;-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This:

```
y = (8 - x) % 7
```

This is how I arrived at that:

```
x  8-x  (8-x)%7
----------------
0   8     1
1   7     0
2   6     6
3   5     5
4   4     4
5   3     3
6   2     2
```

Comment: As for why they are equivalent: in modulus 7, `6 == -1` and `8 == 1`, so `x*6 + 1 == (-1)x + 1 == (-1)x + 8`

Answer (score 26):

```
int f(int x)
{
    return x["I@Velcro"] & 7;
}
```

Comment: @Kugel: that's a simple lookup table with a bit of C obfuscation. x["I@Velcro"] means the same thing as "I@Velcro"[x] (both means *(x + "I@Velcro")). That is "get the character a position x". Every character has an ascii code and with & 7 you only keep the 3 lower digits... and it works. Some fun.

Comment: The fun bit was using grep to try to find words I could stick in the string with the correct lowest three bits.

Comment: +1 for getting an actual WTF? and making me laugh. Kugel is learning a lot today, and that's what SO is all about ;-)

Comment: Haha, based on the WTFs/min principle (http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m), this would have to be some of the worst code ever. *I* like it, though.

Answer (score 23):

0.048611x^6 - 0.9625x^5 + 7.340278x^4 - 26.6875x^3 + (45 + 1/9)x^2 - 25.85x + 1

Sometimes the simple ways are best. ;)

Comment: @Matthew: Dare I even ask how you derived this result?

Comment: hh polynomial regression :-)?

Comment: @Nathan, I have discovered a truly marvelous proof that these are the precise coefficients.  However, this margin is too narrow to contain it.

Comment: That could be wrapped in a general-purpose polynomial class with an array of coefficients, and a length. There would be an evaluate method and....

Comment: @Nathan - He got this via polynomial interpretation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Answer (score 16):

It looks like:

`y = (x * 6 + 1) % 7`

Answer (score 13):

I don't really like the % operator since it does division so:

```
y = (641921 >> (x*3)) & 7;
```

But then you said something about not using lookup tables so maybe this doesn't work for you :-)

**Update:**
Since you want to actually use this in real code and cryptic numbers are not nice, I can offer this more maintainable variant:

```
y = (0x2345601 >> (x*4)) & 15;
```

Comment: @Kugel: hint convert magic number to binary and you may see the light)

Comment: All the values from 0 to 6 can be fit into different positions in just nine bits, like: 000101100. If we could just find the way to translate x into the right index, we could get a formula like `44 >> (x ? ?) & 7`...

Answer (score 6):

Though it seems a bunch of correct answers have already appeared, I figured I'd post this just to show another way to have worked it out (they're all basically variations on the same thing):

Well, the underlying pattern is pretty simple:

```
x y
0 6
1 5
2 4
3 3
4 2 
5 1
6 0

y = 6 - x
```

Your data just happens to have the y values shifted "down" by two indices (or to have the x values shifted "up").

So you need a function to shift the x value. This should do it:

```
x = (x + 5) % 7;
```

Resulting equation:

```
y = 6 - ((x + 5) % 7);
```

Answer (score 4):

Combining the ideas in Dave and Paul's answer gives the rather elegant:

```
y = (8 - x) % 7`
```

(though I see I was beaten to the punch with this)

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned short convertNumber(unsigned short input) {
  if (input <= 1) { return !input; } //convert 0 => 1, 1 => 0
  return (8-input); //convert 2 => 6 ... 6 => 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Homework?

How about:

```
y = (x <= 1 ? 1 : 8) - x
```

Answer (score 1):

> and no, i dont/cant just store the array, and do the lookup.

Why not?

> yes, the input will always be the finite set of 0 to 6. it wont be scaling later.

Just use a bunch of conditionals then.

```
if (input == 0) return 1;
else if (input == 1) return 0;
else if (input == 2) return 6;
...
```

Or find a formula if it's easy to see one, and it is here:

```
if (input == 0) return 1;
else if (input == 1) return 0;
else return 8 - input;
```

Here's a way to avoid both modulo and conditionals, going from this:

`y = (8 - x) % 7`

We know that `x % y = x - floor(x/y)*y`

So we can use `y = 8 - x - floor((8 - x) / 7) * 7`

Comment: @kriss: it's mostly a theoretical achievement, but in rare cases you might not even have a modulo function or it might be slower than division.

Comment: @|V|lad: I just wanted to point out that mod and div are usually the same low level operation `modiv` at processor level, hence your suggestion is not very much interesting as there is other ways to avoid both % and /. But indeed I know of (poorly designed) languages where you just have +-*/ (never saw mod slower than div).

Answer (score 1):

What about some bit-fu ?

You can get the result using only minus, logical operators and shifts.

```
b = (x >> 2) | ((x >> 1) & 1)
y = ((b << 3)|(b ^ 1)) - x
```